# iOS WebView opens Call Popup (tel: link) multiple times upon pressing cancel

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webview

The following popup keeps popping back up multiple times after pressing cancel.

The dialogue looks like the below:

[image]

It's triggered using a tel: link.

Please note, I am using Apache Cordova with the [In App Browser Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html).